# Validating fields in Kendo/Angular Tabstrip

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LKp6DUkybCGk3bfSNX0I?p=preview) I have a Kendo Tabstrip and in the first tab some fields within a Kendo Validator. The first field is required, and if you tab out of that field you will see the error message.

There are two issues:

(1) If you click on "Validate" you don't see the message.
(2) If you tab out of the second field, the error message in the first field disappears.

How to make this validation work?

HTML:

```
<div kendo-tab-strip="">
  <ul>
    <li class="k-state-active">Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>

  <div>
      This is Tab 1 
     <table kendo-validator="validator" k-options="validatorOptions">
        <tr>
           <td>Field 1</td>
           <td>
                <input ng-model="field1" required="" />
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Field 2</td>
           <td>
                <input ng-model="field2" />
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button ng-click="validate()">Validate</button>
  </div>

  <div>
      This is Tab 2 
   </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.validate = function(){
     if (!$scope.validator.validate()) {
        return;
      }
      alert('field is valid');
   };


  $scope.validatorOptions = {
       messages: {
             required: "This field is required"
       }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `kendo-validator` needs to be applied on `form` element. Second, specify `ng-submit` on form element instead of `ng-click` on `button`

```
<form kendo-validator="validator" k-options="validatorOptions" ng-submit="validate($event)">
```

Third, your button should be `type="submit"`

```
<button type="submit">Validate</button>
```

Finally , your `input` elements should have a `name` and `validationMessage`

```
name="fullname" placeholder="Full name" validationMessage="This field is required"
```

Here is a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xznzjr1gSgKYw6LFsK7e?p=preview) modified based on your example.

Comment: I don't see the error message next to the field when I click on Validate

Comment: I don't think you mentioned this requirement in your question. If so please update your question.

Comment: see issue (1) If you click on "Validate" you don't see the message

Comment: yes but it didn't say "next to the field". check the updated plnkr now.